# How to merge rows in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
key   value
1     'aaa'
1     'bbb'
2     'ccc'
2     'ddd'
```

And I want to get a new dataframe where the values are concatenated by keys:

```
key   value
1     'aaabbb'
2     'cccddd'
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: `df.groupby('key').agg(''.join)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
>>> df.groupby("key").apply(lambda x: pd.Series({"value": "'" + "".join(x.value).replace("'", "") + "'"})).reset_index()
   key      value
0    1   'aaabbb'
1    2  'cccdddd'
```

Comment: For the down voter: why exactly is it wrong answer ?

Comment: I didn't but I believe your answer is partially correct.  It should be `df.groupby("key").apply(lambda x: pd.Series({"value": "".join(x.value).replace("'", '')})).reset_index()`

Comment: Hm, good point. I never know, whether these extra quotes are part of the string or descriptor of string. Assuming - part of the string - I edited my answer.